# Dividing a webapp's processes across multiple servers

Tags: performance, server, load-balancing, distributed-computing, database-performance

Distributed System being the correct term i think.

At the moment i am developing a webapp. I am developing it locally, and when it goes into Beta it will be running on one machine, a Linode server probably.

The thing is, this application will be handling and processing large amounts of data based on user requests, and will have numerous scripts running fulltime in the background of the server performing data processing. There wont be a massive amount of users using this system during Beta testing, so one machine will probably have enough resources to run the application smooth enough.

But i cant imagine scaling this application on machine. So probably in the future i will have to spread the application across a distributed system.

I have no idea what this would involve! and find it hard to find simplistic material about this subject online.

I have ideas on how it might be divided up though. The application is consists of a PHP framework, a MySQL database and has some Python scripts that will be ran forever handling automated tasks and data processing.

Maybe each seperate part gets its own machine, the PHP on one machine, this is the one that handles user requests and the related processing, the database on its own machine, and the Python scripts running on their own machine.

But i have absolutely no idea how this might be achieved!

What i would really like is if you guys could give some simple explanations, or a general overview, of how you would divide up an application across multiple machines. Technologies involved, general concepts, anything!

any help or discussion greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a huge topic area with way too many options to list in total. But at a high level there are a couple of approaches that differ according to the use case and dictate some of the technologies that can be used.

First, and most importantly, you need think about how data flows through the system. Is it a synchronous or asynchronous system? Meaning, when a request comes in to your web app, does it need to make an additional request to the background process and wait for a result? Or can the background process do its thing asynchronously?

It sounds like this is an asynchronous system. For this use case, logging may become critical. It's common to use something like [Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org) (a distributed log) to store events that will be processed asynchronously. In that type of workflow (without knowing your specific use case) the web app might write some data to a Kafka topic and a consumer (your Python process) on another group of machines consumes from that topic and processes the messages. Kafka will handle evenly distributing the load between the consumers. Of course, there are a lot of similar messaging technologies as well.

For the web app, you simply put a load balancer in front of a set of servers running the app.

This is really a simple but very effective architecture that will scale for your needs. If your processing becomes too intensive, most architectures integrate heavier weight distributed processing frameworks like Hadoop (batch), Storm (stream), and Spark (batch & stream), but those technologies are really complex and have a high learning curve, especially if you don't have a running start with distributed systems.

Finally, there are some really nice distributed systems frameworks like [Vert.x](http://vertx.io) and [Akka](http://akka.io) that greatly simplify building this type of microservice architecture by abstracting location and communication details.

Here's a really popular introduction to the concept of a distributed log and its use cases:
[The Log: What every software engineer should know about real-time data's unifying abstraction](https://engineering.linkedin.com/distributed-systems/log-what-every-software-engineer-should-know-about-real-time-datas-unifying)

Comment: thanks for the reply. Things like the python scripts will run in the background, never intereacting with users. The PHP side of it, will be handling most of the user interactions, there are web pages that have continuously looped AJAX calls to the PHP scripts on the server, these scripts will be querying the database and crunching some numbers and returning the results. Its more so these processes that will take up recources i think. In a distributed system, even though the whole project may exist on one machine, its possible to still use the CPU and memory of the other machines right?